# connect to Binance websocket api from Nestjs

Tags: node.js, websocket, nestjs, gateway

I wanna connect to the binance websocket api but I don't know how

I tried connecting to a specific url by making nestjs server a client but it doesn't console.log 'connected to the binance'

```
import { Injectable, OnModuleInit } from '@nestjs/common';
import { io, Socket } from 'socket.io-client'

@Injectable()
export class BinanceGateway implements OnModuleInit {
    public binanceClient: Socket

    constructor() {
        this.binanceClient = io('https://api.binance.com')
    }

    onModuleInit() {
        console.log('hello')
        this.registerConsumerEvents()
    }

    registerConsumerEvents() {
        this.binanceClient.on('connect', () => {
            console.log('connected to the binance')
        })
    }

}
```

Comment: have you read the binance websocket api documentation ?, https://binance-docs.github.io/apidocs/websocket_api/en/#general-info I assume you would want to call their testnet first  wss://testnet.binance.vision/ws-api/v3

Answer (score 0):

I find the solution to my question.
In order to access the binance websocket api with Nest.js, first, import binance-api-node :

```
const Binance = require('binance-api-node').default;
```

Then initialize it in the constructor of BinanceGateway class :

```
constructor() {
  this.binanceClient = Binance()
}
```

Now you can get data from binanceClient; In my case I wanna get Candle Data So to get Candle Data :

```
this.binanceClient.ws.candles('ETHBTC', '1m', candle => {
  console.log(candle)
})
```

Now, The final version of binance.gateway.ts is :

```
import { Injectable, OnModuleInit } from '@nestjs/common';
const Binance = require('binance-api-node').default;

@Injectable()
export class BinanceGateway implements OnModuleInit {
  public binanceClient: any

  constructor() {
    this.binanceClient = Binance()
  }

  onModuleInit() {
    console.log('hooooy')
    this.binanceClient.ws.candles('ETHBTC', '1m', candle => {
      console.log(candle)
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: What if I want it dynamic? Let's say everytime a user register to the app I want to connect to binance api and save their trade logs to database by listening to binance websocket api. Lets say each user has different api and private keys. And then they have option to stop saving their trade logs. How do I do it?